# Pass ownership of method argument to 'try with resources' block

Tags: java, try-with-resources

I have a question regarding Java's 'try with resources' feature. Most examples seem to follow the model where the resource is declared and instantiated inside the try statement as in the following:

```
try (BufferedReader in =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); ) {
  ...
}
```

I need to pass a closeable resource to a method and I was wondering if it was possible or advisable to pass ownership of a closeable resource passed as a method argument to a try block. For example:

```
void handleConnection(Socket clientSocket) {
    try (Socket socket = clientSocket;
         BufferedReader in =
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); ) {
        ...
    }
```

Will this properly clean up the clientSocket instance? I am hoping to avoid explicitly closing the clientSocket instance in my code.

Comment: If you do go down this path, make sure to document it. Typically, the owner of the closable should be responsible for closing it.

Comment: I could see why it might be dangerous given that some other code could attempt to use the socket after it has been closed. I was mainly interested to know if it works the way I expect it to.

Comment: I would _really quite strongly_ advise against this.  The creator of the socket should be responsible for closing it.

Comment: I see why you'd advise against this. The reason I'm wanting to do this is because I'm passing the socket to a child thread to be read asynchronously. It looks like the socket will have to be closed inside the child thread anyways and I want to make use of the cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 3):

While this is technically correct, it is dangerous. Many `AutoCloseable`'s (including `Socket`) cannot be reopened once they're closed. So, the user of your `handleConnection` method has to be aware that the object passed to your method can no longer be used. It is probably a better idea to let the owner of the object handle it's lifecycle. You can achieve that for example by creating a wrapper class, which itself implements `AutoCloseable`, like below.

```
public class SocketHandler implements AutoCloseable {
    private final Socket clientSocket;

    public SocketHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
        if (clientSocket == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Socket cannot be null");
        }
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void handle() {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        clientSocket.close();
    }

}
```